# Why do I cause a segmentation fault when passing pointers between local processes?

Tags: c, pointers, network-programming, segmentation-fault

I am passing an array of pointers from server to client. However on client side I get Segmentation fault when I derefrence the received array. **Server & client both are local to the OS.** I am think I am making some kind of mistake in pointers & violating some pointer rule.

Here is the code:

**Server.c**

```
struct WinGoku goku,windows,gates;

struct WinGoku *array[3];
array[0] = &goku;
array[1] = &windows;
array[2] = &gates;

send(conSocket, array, sizeof(&array), 0);
```

**Client.c**

```
struct WinGoku **array;

int rec =  recv(mySocket, array, 4, 0);

printf("bytes Recieved %d\n", rec);

int i;
for(i = 0; i<3;i++)
{
    printf("%s\n",array[i]->test);
}
```

`struct WinGoku` contains only `char[50]` in which I am copying data with `strcpy`.

Send & receive are not returning -1, so data is sent and received properly.

What is the mistake that I am doing?

Comment: I segfault when I build arrays a lot, and it's usually because of accidentally going out of bounds, so my first stop is checking to make sure I never ask for information that's not actually there. You should look over _all_ of your code for that, because it's in odd places sometimes.

Comment: @JonahNelson Except that in this case, it's entirely obvious what the problem is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Server & client both are local to the OS. I am sure I am making some kind of mistake in pointers & voilating some pointer rule.

The pointers are in something called ["virtual memory" space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space).  The scope is limited to a single process.

Each of the server, client, despite being on the same computer has their own virtual memory space.  These pointers are invalid in each.  You must [serialize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) (and usually marshal) the contents of memory to be sent over the network.

Comment: Excellent explanatin Brian.

Comment: yep I totally forgot/ignored the concept that every process has it's own memory. Thanks for reminding me :)

Comment: No rule without exceptions. If one process was created by forking the other, and the objects was created before the fork and still exists in both processes, then transfering pointers should work.

Answer (score 5):

You can't send pointers over the network. Well, you *can*, technically, but they won't be pointing to the same thing on the receiving system.

If the actual objects are simple, i.e. contain no pointers, then you can send them directly instead.

Comment: Well I passed address of a struct obj from server & recieved in client. Worked like a charm, why isnt this working?

Comment: @UmerFarooq Yes you can send the pointer, but like I said in my updated answer, it won't be pointing to the same thing in the other program.

Comment: @UmerFarooq It's the same thing with saving pointers to a file, and then reading them later, it simply won't point to anything you have allocated.

Comment: You will get the memory address that is only valid in the sending machine.

Comment: @Tarik Don't worry about it, I'll survive. :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The memory address server passed to client is same for both because they are on the same machine.

Comment: @Tarik "Server & client both are local to the OS." It's not a different machine. It's a different **process.**

Comment: @JoachimPileborg LOL I think Tarik is talking about Downvote on my question. :P

Comment: @UmerFarooq In that case read about virtual memory. Two processes, even if from the same program, have all private memory maps. Just because a structure is placed at a certain address in process A, it may not be in process B. And todays operating systems can even randomize the memory addresses of programs it loads, to foil certain security attacks, which make it even harder to share addresses.

Comment: @UmerFarooq, then he would post it on the question above...and not this answer

Comment: @UmerFarooq You are working in virtual address space that maps pointers to different physical memory addresses for different processes...unless you are still using DOS :-)

Comment: @Tarik Yep I remember that now. I learned it in OS class, but somehow I forgot that totally. My loss :D

Comment: By the way, if you are into communicating by passing pointers, I am pretty sure there exists a memory sharing mechanism in the O.S.

Answer (score 0):

sizeof(&array) isnt the size of struct WinGoku * 3

it should be `(3*sizeof(WinGoku))`

**Edit:**

pointers of a process cannot be accessed in another proccess.
you should send the whole between server and client.

Comment: he should serialize his structures into an array of bytes

Comment: It's like talking about how bad the paint of a blown up building is.